# How to count frequency of first letters of strings?

Tags: python, frequency

I have a list of strings in my program, for example:

[ 'home', 'dog', 'park', 'house', 'hotel', 'fire' ]

and I want to know which is the most first frequent  letter .

for example in that string is the letter H because it is in hotel, house and home.

I tried just 2 for cycles but I didn't get the result

Comment: Just 2 what? You should loop over the array, use `element[0]` to get the first character, and count the frequencies of those.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a list of the first letters and then use the max() function to get the highest number of occurrences in it.

```
lst = ['home', 'dog', 'park', 'house', 'hotel', 'fire']
max([item[0] for item in lst], key=lst.count)
```

output

```
'h'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first letter of each work with a list comprehension.

Then you can use `collections.Counter` to find the frequency of each letter and find the maximum of the returned dictionary:

```
import collections

words = [ 'home', 'dog', 'park', 'house', 'hotel', 'fire' ]

first_letters = [w[0] for w in words]

f = collections.Counter(first_letters)

print(max(f, key=f.get))
```

Output: `h`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of the first character of each string and then use python's statistics module like so:

```
from statistics import mode
def most_common_first_letter(words):
    first_letters = []
    for word in words:
        first_letters.append(word[0])
    return mode(first_letters)
```

This uses the mode function to find the most common letter in the list of first letters.

Comment: Short version: `mode(next(zip(*words)))`

Comment: Yes, that does work. I just wanted it to be easy to understand for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter from collections module, for example:

```py
from collections import Counter


list_ = ['home', 'dog', 'park', 'house', 'hotel', 'fire']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = Counter(word[0] for word in list_)
    print(counter.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting first elemnt from list item & Using collections

```
from collections import Counter
ls= [ 'home', 'dog', 'park', 'house', 'hotel', 'fire' ]
ls = [w[0] for w in ls]

s=(Counter(ls))

print(max(s, key=s.get))
```

output #

```
h
```